# How to set an environment variable in maven depending on the OS

Tags: linux, windows, maven

I am fairly new to maven. I have setup a pom.xml which defines a profile for running my unit tests. I am trying to set Path environment variable. The env variable name is Path for Windows and LD_LIBRARY_PATH for Linux.  I don't want to keep on changing these env. variable names depending on the OS. How should I achieve this?

```
<profile>
        <id>integration-tests</id>
        <build>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tychoVersion}</version>
                <configuration combine.self="override">
                    <argLine>${tycho.testArgLine} ${global.test.vmargs} ${bundle.test.vmargs}</argLine>
                    <forkMode>${bundle.test.forkMode}</forkMode>
                    <useUIHarness>${bundle.test.useUIHarness}</useUIHarness>
                    <useUIThread>${bundle.test.useUIThread}</useUIThread>
                    <environmentVariables>
                      <!--For windows change LD_LIBRARY_PATH to PATH-->
                        <LD_LIBRARY_PATH>${dependenciesDir}${path.separator}{env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH}</LD_LIBRARY_PATH>

                    </environmentVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        </build>

    </profile>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Profile activation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) might help here.  Remove the `<environmentVariables>` config from the integration tests profile.  Then add the profiles below, tweaking the `<activation>` sections to meet the specific requirements.  You do not need to explicitly enable these profiles on the command line; Maven will activate the right profile based on which system is running the build.

```
<profile>
  <id>windows-tests</id>
  <activation>
      <os>
        <family>Windows</family>
      </os>
  </activation>
  <build>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tychoVersion}</version>
            <configuration>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <PATH>${dependenciesDir}${path.separator}{env.PATH}</PATH>
                </environmentVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>linux-tests</id>
  <activation>
      <os>
        <family>Linux</family>
      </os>
  </activation>
  <build>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tychoVersion}</version>
            <configuration>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <LD_LIBRARY_PATH>${dependenciesDir}${path.separator}{env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH}</LD_LIBRARY_PATH>

                </environmentVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: Is there a way to combine this activation conditions in one profile?

Comment: Not that I know of.  You want one to run for Linux, one for Windows.  Those are entirely different OS, thus entirely different activation criteria.  Profile activation doesn't have the concept of "condition 1 OR condition 2" unfortunately.  I seem to remember seeing JIRA issues requesting that kind of feature, not sure what the status is.

Comment: hello, i have same problem, and under linux no problem, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is correctly defined, but for windows profile, my path is not changed...so problem persist :( i have done a copy/paste on your solution and change version and i m not using tycho but maven-surefire-plugin. thanks for your help

Comment: Perhaps the value of `family` specified in the profile isn't what the OS is using.  There are [rules](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireOS.html) for operating system determination.  Check the value of the corresponding property on your system and use that in the profile.